# How to execute windows command from web browser?

Tags: browser

I wanted to run windows command from google chrome without installing any extensions.

I am okay to import any js files that supports it, but don't want to install any extensions as I cannot ask my end users to install these extensions in their web browsers.

I want something similar to jenkins which allows to run commands and displaying the outputs in browser only directly, but something easy and simple.

I tried to import subprocess module in brython, but that gave

```
NameError: name 'java' is not defined
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `python`?

Comment: This can't be done in general, it's considered a security risk.

Comment: This error just says you have not define `java`? Perhaps you meant to pass it as string `"java"`

Comment: Have you considered what happens if you go to a website that's using this technique and it runs `format c:` or maybe just `del c:\windows\*.*`...